# How to install de_DE.iso88591? (JasperReports Umlaute problem on Rockylinux)

Tags: java, linux, encoding, jasper-reports, locale

I use Docker Base Image rockylinux/rockylinux:8.4 and Oracle Java JDK 8 to compile JasperReports (v6) containing German Umlaute characters.
In the produced PDF they're displayed as "?".
If I compile the JasperReport on the host the PDF contains the correct character "ä".
On the host "locale -a" contains "de_DE.iso88591" in the output. That's not the case in the container. Which package do I have to install to install de_DE.iso88591?

```
locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

locale -a

C
C.utf8
de_AT
de_AT@euro
de_AT.utf8
de_BE
de_BE@euro
de_BE.utf8
de_CH
de_CH.utf8
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_IT
de_IT.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU
de_LU@euro
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
...

locale -m

...
ISO-8859-1
ISO-8859-10
ISO-8859-11
ISO-8859-13
ISO-8859-14
ISO-8859-15
...
```

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` might be worth examining on both systems. Then you could use the appropriate `javac -encoding` parameter for the target

Comment: file.encoding is ANSI_X3.4-1968 in the container. UTF-8 on host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using an resource bundle key instead of the plain text we managed to get it work. In the resource bundle key we use escaping for Umlaute. That solves the problem for us. However, I still don't know how to install de_DE.iso88591